# ....... build.gradle

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle

Что может быть причиной, того, что в проекте только один build.gradle вместо двух. В директориях проекта и app оба они есть.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Clear, Rebuild, Invalidate Cache and Restart пробовал.

Comment: а вы проект пробовали запустить где-то?

Comment: Да, запускал на устройстве. Без проблем. Только не работает Instant Run. Возможно из-за этого.

Comment: попробуйте включить это функцию может поможет, потому-что вообще чаще всего создается два файла, либо попробуйте создать новый проект

Comment: Instant Run у меня включён. При создании нового проекта оба есть.

Comment: то есть оба нужных вам файла находятся там где вам нужно при создании проекта с `InstantRun`? или опять та же ситуация?

Comment: Instant Run это мои догадки. Пока его не нужно брать в расчёт. Просто нужно чтобы студия увидела и отобразила оба градла. Если создать проект с нуля, то она создаёт и отображает оба.

Comment: а у вас этот проект уже с чем-то или еще пустой? просто если при создании нового проекта вы включили instant run, то походу он был выключен при создании этого проекта

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35168753/instant-run-in-android-studio-2-0-how-to-turn-off

Comment: Этот проект рабочий ("с чем-то"). И  Instant Run включён и не влияет ни на что (за исключением того что он не работает).

Comment: тогда это странно очень, ведь если при создании проекта была включена эта функция то должен появится второй файл, я тогда еще погуглю по этой теме, а зачем вам вообще этот файл градла? библиотеку подключаете?

Comment: Нет. Пытаюсь разобраться почему не работает Instant Run при том что он включён. Всё уже перепробовал. Увидел эту несостыковку и решил поискать ответ, почему так получается.

Comment: Похоже на глюк китайского планшета. После сброса его настроек Instant Run заработал.

Comment: вы на планшете пишете программу? или это трансформер какой-то? или вы о чем вообще?

Comment: Пишу в Android Studio

Comment: Запускаю на планшете

Comment: а все я тогда понял)